My computer suddenly can't resolve stackoverflow.com
My computer is running Windows 10 22H2 19045.5011, today it suddenly can't resolve (just) stackoverflow.com, both ping and tracert can't work, here is the behaviour in cmd:
E:\>ipconfig /flushdns

Windows IP Configuration

Successfully flushed the DNS Resolver Cache.

E:\>ping stackoverflow.com
Ping request could not find host stackoverflow.com. Please check the name and try again.

E:\>tracert stackoverflow.com
Unable to resolve target system name stackoverflow.com.

I will first summarize the items I have checked, and I will put down the results later.

DNS
hosts
firewall
proxy & VPN


At first glance, it appears to be a DNS server issue, but nslookup works:
E:\>nslookup stackoverflow.com
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  192.168.0.99

Name:    stackoverflow.com
Served by:
- damian.ns.cloudflare.com
          172.64.35.50
          108.162.195.50
          162.159.44.50
          2803:f800:50::6ca2:c332
          2a06:98c1:50::ac40:2332
          2606:4700:58::a29f:2c32
          stackoverflow.com
- sureena.ns.cloudflare.com
          172.64.34.126
          108.162.194.126
          162.159.38.126
          2606:4700:50::a29f:267e
          2803:f800:50::6ca2:c27e
          2a06:98c1:50::ac40:227e
          stackoverflow.com

I also checked the hosts file and no problems:
E:\>type c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
# Copyright (c) 1993-2009 Microsoft Corp.
#
# This is a sample HOSTS file used by Microsoft TCP/IP for Windows.
#
# This file contains the mappings of IP addresses to host names. Each
# entry should be kept on an individual line. The IP address should
# be placed in the first column followed by the corresponding host name.
# The IP address and the host name should be separated by at least one
# space.
#
# Additionally, comments (such as these) may be inserted on individual
# lines or following the machine name denoted by a '#' symbol.
#
# For example:
#
#      102.54.94.97     rhino.acme.com          # source server
#       38.25.63.10     x.acme.com              # x client host

# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
127.0.0.1       localhost
::1             localhost

I haven't installed any firewall or antivirus software except for Windows Defender. I have also tried to turn off its firewall, but that also didn't work.
No proxy or VPN is activated.
Finally I tried to use Wireshark to capture DNS and ICMP traffic (only DNS traffic was captured):
39  17.066267   192.168.0.104   192.168.0.99    DNS 77  Standard query 0x1854 A stackoverflow.com
40  17.067214   192.168.0.99    192.168.0.104   DNS 420 Standard query response 0x1854 A stackoverflow.com
                                                        NS damian.ns.cloudflare.com NS sureena.ns.cloudflare
                                                        .com A 172.64.35.50 A 108.162.195.50
                                                        A 162.159.44.50 A 172.64.34.126 A 108.162.194.126
                                                        A 162.159.38.126 AAAA 2803:f800:50::6ca2:c332
                                                        ......

Every time I executed the ping command, a pair of corresponding DNS request and response were generated, but I noticed that the ping command immediately displayed an error after execution (before receiving the DNS response), which is very strange.
I could successfully resolve to other URLs, even if www.stackoverflow.com, through ping. Even for non-existent URLs, ping would wait for about 1s before displaying an error, except for stackoverflow.com.
At this point, I really don't know what other settings can be checked. Please give me some advice. Thanks in advance.

That doesn't look like "nslookup works" – it returns an answer, yes, but not the kind of answer that a general-use DNS server is supposed to return to clients. (It only returns a delegation, not a final address answer, and Windows doesn't support following delegations.) What kind of device is 192.168.0.99? Is it your router or some RPi or something else?

What firmware or what DNS software does your router run? What upstream DNS server is your router configured to use?

Thank you for your prompt, that's helpful and enough. It seems that my router cached this incorrect DNS query because its DNS server can return a result that looks different. The problem was resolved after restarting the router. Do you mind writing an answer?

"Served by" in the nslookup output shows your DNS server (well, your router) returning a referral reply – pointing not to the actual address being requested, but to another set of DNS servers that the client is supposed to query again.
Windows does not support following referrals; it only has a minimal DNS client that relies on the DNS server to do all of the referral chasing before returning the final answer. (Nslookup.exe uses a built-in DNS client instead of the Windows one, but likewise it's a very minimal client that doesn't follow referrals.)
The router's DNS software itself most likely relies on another upstream DNS server (usually the ISP's) to handle referrals, and it just proxies whatever answer it gets, which would mean that the upstream DNS server returned an incorrect reply and the router cached it – it returned a referral to the router even though it should've followed it up. (Though I can imagine other possibilities, e.g. the router's DNS cache mixing up packets, etc.)
